# Proof-Verification that Union of three subspaces is subspace iff one of the spaces contains the other two

Tags: proof-verification, vector-spaces

I know people have asked this problem before but I am looking for an original proof verification.

Going through all the problems of a textbook so problem 12 simply states 
"the union of two subspaces is a subspace, then one subspace is contained in the other".

My proof:

Let $A, B, C$ be three subspaces. Then, without loss of generality, we have the following cases: $A$ contains one or both of $B$ or $C$ or, each subspace contains an element not in the union of the other two.

From problem 12, the first case automatically implies that $B, C \subset A$. To prove that the second case is impossible, we first prove that there exists a non-zero $b \in B$ and non-zero $c \in C$ such that $(b + c) \notin A$. Since $(b+c) \notin B, C$, we will have found an element outside of the union so that the union is not a subspace, a contradiction.

Suppose $A$ contains the set of all possible sums of non-zero $b,c$ from $B, C$, respectively. First, choose $b \in B - (A \cup C)$ and $c \in C - (A \cup B)$. Then $(b \pm c) \in A$. This implies that $2b = (b + c) + (b -
 c) \in A$. Therefore, $b \in A$, a contradiction.

Comment: and where is problem 12?

Comment: This fails in characteristic $2$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, Axler mentions this result is not true for fields of characteristic 2.

Comment: I'm solving this problem and stuck on it too. Do you mind elaborate more on it? How did you give the suppose condition that A contains all the possible sums of non-zero pair of b and c such that it leads to a contradiction? The second case is that each subspace contains elements that others subspaces don't right?